# Deleting Root Node

Tags: python

I learned this Python Implementation to delete the root node from a Binary Search Tree on Youtube. I understood everything in this program except for the two star-marked lines.

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.lchild = None
        self.rchild = None
    
    def insert(self, data):
        if self.key is None:
            self.key = data
            return
        if self.key == data:
            return
        if self.key > data:
            if self.lchild:
                self.lchild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.lchild = BST(data)
        else:
            if self.rchild:
                self.rchild.insert(data)
            else:
                self.rchild = BST(data)
                
    def preorder(self):
        print(self.key, end=' ')
        if self.lchild:
            self.lchild.preorder()
        if self.rchild:
            self.rchild.preorder()
            
    def delete(self, data, curr): #curr=root.key
        if self.key > data:
            if self.lchild:
                self.lchild = self.lchild.delete(data, curr)
            else:
                print("Node is not present")
        elif self.key < data:
            if self.rchild:
                self.rchild = self.rchild.delete(data, curr)
            else:
                print("Node note present")
        else:
            if self.lchild is None:
                temp = self.rchild
                if data == curr:
                    self.key = temp.key
                    self.lchild = temp.lchild
                    self.rchild = temp.rchild
                    temp = None
                **self = None**
                **return temp**
            if self.rchild is None:
                temp = self.lchild
                if data == curr:
                    self.key = temp.key
                    self.lchild = temp.lchild
                    self.rchild = temp.rchild
                    temp = None
                **self = None
                return temp**
            node = self.rchild
            while node.lchild:
                node = node.lchild
            self.key = node.key
            self.rchild = self.rchild.delete(self.key, curr)
        return self
        
def count(node):
    if node is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1+count(node.lchild)+count(node.rchild)
       


root = BST(10)
list1 = [1, 12]
for i in list1:
    root.insert(i)

if count(root) > 1:
    root.delete(10, root.key) 
else:
    print("Can't perform deletion operation")

print()    
print("after deleting:")
root.preorder()
```

I can't understand how **self = None** is working in the else part and why **return temp** is not right under the else block. If I take the **return temp** statement right under
**temp = None**, and remove **self = None**, I get an error which says: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lchild'**

Please explain to me the role of the two star-marked lines in this program, and why it raises an exception if I put **return temp** right under
**temp = None**

```
             else:
                if self.lchild is None:
                    temp = self.rchild
                    if data == curr:
                        self.key = temp.key
                        self.lchild = temp.lchild
                        self.rchild = temp.rchild
                        temp = None
                    **self = None
                    return temp**
                if self.rchild is None:
                    temp = self.lchild
                    if data == curr:
                        self.key = temp.key
                        self.lchild = temp.lchild
                        self.rchild = temp.rchild
                        temp = None
                    **self = None**
                    **return temp**
```

Comment: It'll be helpful in solving the question if the referred link for the youtube video might be provided as well to get a better context of the code..

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer Programmer sure, here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2gWBkiboGY&list=PLzgPDYo_3xukPJdH6hVQ6Iic7KiJuoA-l&index=50